# Is there a way to embed a Leaflet map into a Wordpress theme website?

Tags: leaflet, qgis2web, wordpress

I recently decided to make my own website, but chose to use a Wordpress theme to save me time in designing. Unfortunately it primary uses php which I am not familiar with and end up breaking my page after attempts to edit. Is there a relatively simple way to place my webmap from QGIS2Web in wordpress? Potentially in my portfolio or another page?

This question [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/147023/how-do-i-embed-the-a-leaflet-map-into-my-web-page-using-qgis2leaf) is fairly similar, but I'm not working in html.

Comment: Wordpress uses php, but also html and javascript. You can edit one of the page templates (mixed php and html) to include an iframe as in the answer you linked to. There probably is not a plug-in or some non code-based solution, so ultimately you are going to have to edit some php, html and/or javascript. You may need to post some code you are working with to get answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe there might be one or more iframe plugins for WordPress. If so, an iframe is the simplest way to embed a map.

Comment: I was eventually able to get this to work. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case you have not already tried, there are 2 plugins that integrate Leaflet into WordPress:

- [Leaflet-map](https://wordpress.org/plugins/leaflet-map/)
- [Maps Marker Pro](https://www.mapsmarker.com/)

Leaflet Plugins page also references other platforms.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I saw maps marker pro and it wasn't what I needed. But I never saw the leaflet-map plugin! I'll try it tonight, thanks!

Comment: The plugin has no directions for self hosting other than saying it is available in the dashboard. Dashboard now contains 2 spots to place your single css file and single js file. I have 5+ files for each. Also it has no information on how to actually host that webmap on a particular page. I'm a bit confused as I figured I would just give it the html file. I'm sure it would work, I'm just not sure how.

Comment: Yep, neither would embed an HTML web map (I manage the first one). Very interesting thing you're trying to do though. I haven't worked extensively with QGIS.